# unordered_map bugging out when assigning or inserting

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Whenever I try to initialise/assign or insert a lot of elements at once it won't insert the items and then will skip the rest of the function.

My map is of types int and a struct that holds 6 const char*'s, there are ~70 elements that I want to initialise my map with. Ive tried using less elements (~50) but it still bugs out.

Ive tried debugging it line by line and it will run for the first ~20 elements then after that it will start skipping them, e.g. insert(elem_20) then will skip to insert(elem_22) and {pair20, pair21, pair22} would skip pair21 and go straight to pair22, it seems random as far as I can tell.

I have tried the following :

```
    // global scope, won't initialise the map
    unordered_map<int, struct> my_map = {std::make_pair(...), ...};
```

```
    // in a function
    void init_map() 
    {
        // my_map is defined in the global scope
        // won't be assigned
        my_map = { std::make_pair(...), ... };

        // this will be skipped
        other_func();
        ... 
    }
```

```
    // in a function
    void init_map_insert() 
    {
        // will insert the first 20 or so then gets buggy after that
        // my_map is defined in the global scope
        my_map.insert(std::make_pair(...));
        my_map.insert(std::make_pair(...));
        my_map.insert(std::make_pair(...));
        ... 

        // this will be skipped
        other_func();
        ... 
    }
```

Video of the problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIg6bn6fB6E

You can see the first breakpoint getting triggered but then the breakpoints at the end of the of the function aren't triggered, as well as the breakpoint right after the function call.

I am using Xcode on MacOS 10.14.

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Edit : sorry, I'm not that good at explaining

Edit 2 : Added video

Comment: How do you know it skips?

Comment: Craft a [mcve] showing the problem. We need more than just "then gets buggy".  I'd say run valgrind over this, but if your Mojave is like mine, there isn't one available. High Sierra was the last bastion of that goodness.

Comment: @user253751the breakpoints aren't triggered

Comment: @WhozCraig The "buggy" parts are the skipping of elements and then it skipping the rest of the function, as for the example its just inserting ~70 elements into a map

Comment: *"sorry, I'm not that good at explaining"* - and that's why we ask that you post *real* code that produces the *real* problem. It doesn't have to be the code you discovered the problem with; it just has to reproduce whatever the issue is *for us*. Craft what you're doing in a stand-along source file with sufficient code to reproduce the issue *for us* when we copy/paste/compile/run said-same. Post that, and we have a genuine [mcve] that we can work with. Between that and your description, we can probably figure out what is happening.

Comment: @WhozCraig its literally just inserting ~70 elements, why do you need an example for that?

Comment: Back at ya. Why wouldn't you post an example of that? I have a suspicion, but right now it's a wag (wild arse guess), and that makes for lousy answers. I can confirm/rebuke that suspicion if I see something from you that actually produces the problem.

Comment: Because you don't need an example of that?  Look at the code in my post, its just that x70

Comment: The code you posted is totally valid. There might be something wrong in other parts of the code. Try to use some memchecking tool like valgrind.

Comment: "The breakpoints aren't triggered" isn't a foolproof way to know things are skipped. Between optimizing compilers and debug symbol inaccuracies, breakpoints are not a reliable way to determine what's really happening in your program (unless you are compiling without optimizations). Does the program actually produce incorrect output? Or does the debugger just do things you don't understand?

Comment: I mean so far every breakpoint (in every project) I have placed has been triggered up until this so they seem fairly reliable, and the why would the code be optimised out if its being used? There is no output in my project, it just stops working after the assignment / insertions

Comment: See here for an example where 4 lines of code are optimized into a single instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/x5WzNH (which means your debugger won't be able to step to each line). Or, a more trivial example: https://godbolt.org/z/EfHePR. But if your program crashes then that is indeed a clear indication that a problem exists.

Comment: @MaxLanghof wouldnt it just optimise the whole assignment instead of just random elements? and there's no crash its as if the thread is being killed right after the assignment

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave this as an answer even though it shouldn't be because you didn't provide any reproducible code or enough information so I can only guess here. When using a `map` of any kind, including of course `unordered_map`, it will only allow one entry per key. You did not specify how your key is determined but my guess is that you have cases where a new value is entered but overwrites an existing key.

Comment: how hard it is to reproduce 70 inserts? As for the keys, each one is unique, Ive double checked like 50 times

Comment: Its not about *how hard* it is, you didn't provide enough information. For example you did not share how the key is generated.

Comment: Its just an enum, Ill make a video of the problem since Im horrible at explaining

Comment: @oceanman Don't make a video. Please include code in the question that, when compiled and run, produces behavior that you find unexpected (you can hard-code the input into the program). If you do that (and tell us what behavior you expected instead) you will find that you get your question answered very quickly. Online compilers like https://godbolt.org, https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com or https://wandbox.org/ can help you check that your example is complete.

Comment: Its gonna be hard to reproduce since I'm injecting a dylib into another process, IMO a video is the best since y'all not gonna be able to reproduce correctly

Comment: Why is the ``dylib`` necessary at all? You have an ``std::unordered_map`` which is part of the ``STL``. All you need to do is recreate your issue with a minimal example. You said that the key is an enum, but that doesn't help me. What enum? How do you decide what entry in the enum?

Comment: @oceanman Then the first step should be isolating the behavior into a reproducible form. There's no mention of injecting code to other processes in the question, what if that's part of the problem? Right now we are all guessing and poking blindly. We can only tell you for sure where the error is when you post the part of your setup that contains the error, which may be far away from where you observe the symptoms. Please see [mcve].

Comment: @PickleRick my "program" is a dylib which then hooks functions when its injected, watch the vid

Comment: Remember what I said about wags ? Um.. yeah. Btw. [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/dFadAh).

Comment: @MaxLanghof I didn't think the injection has anything to do with the problem since its worked in the past before with other projects that are injected

Comment: Your video did nothing but further confuse me. What exactly is your problem? You break on the map initialization and then continue execution. What is it you're trying to show me? I think you probably want to step rather than continue.

Comment: @oceanman Great, then you should be able to reproduce the problem without injection! I'll be waiting for a [mcve].

Comment: @PickleRick im showing you that that it triggers the first breakpoint but then it doesn't the breakpoints after the assignment. Continue just continues to run the code from the break, it should still trigger the breakpoints at the end since that code hasnt been run yet.

Comment: @MaxLanghof https://ideone.com/dFadAh

Comment: looks like it's working

Comment: Step through the code, BP not being hit does not necessarily mean it isn't reached. I'm not familiar with MacOS at all (even my phone is Android) so I couldn't give you an obvious explanation. It's not a lot of code though so stepping through would give you a much better idea.

Comment: On Mac it should break at all points, its like the threads being killed immediately after assignment

Comment: My comment about not being guaranteed a break has nothing (or rather very little) to do with MacOS. I meant exceptions, branches, BP cleared, debugger settings, etc. For example your debugger could be set to ignore already seen exceptions. You say "It's like the thread is killed" but this can be confirmed very easily. When the first BP breaks, note current thread. Then, after continuing execution, look at the threads list in your debugger. The simplest thing you can do though right now is just step through the debugger rather than resuming execution like you are.

Comment: I said in my post I went thru line by line, but wasn't able to pinpoint anything

Comment: I assume you mean single step when you say line by line? If so, what do you mean you couldn't pinpoint anything? When did execution divert from expected? When did the thread terminate, if it did? You must have gotten some information from single stepping.

Comment: It starts acting out after about 20 elements, I'm not sure if the thread dies but it seems like it does since the rest of the code in the thread after the assignment is never called

Comment: It seems like you don't have much experience debugging. Are you doing ``step over`` or ``step into`` once the BP is hit? At what point does execution "stop" and what does that even mean? Is the thread terminated? Does the map ever get built?

Comment: I just do continue which will then continue to run the code which should then trigger the next bp, execution stops after the assignment/insertions, what does stop usually mean? idk if the thread is terminated, I haven't looked into it yet, and no the map empty afterwards

Comment: bro I give up, thanks for trying to help

Comment: Using ``continue`` will continue execution (until another BP is hit). ``Step over``will single step one instruction at a time while skipping over branch instructions. ``Step into`` is the same as ``step over`` except it will follow branches and continue to single step.

Answer (score 1):

Your unordered_map is initialized here:

```
unordered_map<int, struct> my_map = {std::make_pair(...), ...};
```

then you re-initialized the map in init_map(), which wipes out the what was previously initialized in the list initialization.

```
// in a function
void init_map() 
{
    // my_map is defined in the global scope
    // won't be assigned
    my_map = { std::make_pair(...), ... };
```

Note that my_map = { blah } is equivalent to

```
my_map = unordered_map<int, struct>{blah}
```

which invokes assignment operator of my_map.

This is probably the bug you're talking about.

Comment: I believe those are three seperate *attempts* but in a single code block. This is again why a reproducible example is so useful.

Comment: @PickleRick is correct, they're 3 seperate examples, my bad

Comment: I have proposed an edit that separates the attempts into three separate code blocks.

Comment: Fwiw, given the code, that's likely a move-assignment due to the temporary nature of the rhs of that statement, which [`std::unordered_map` supports](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator%3D).